# How to increase the demand for kosher food?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, tzibur-community, how-to

I live in the Hartford Connecticut area and while the population of people who practice the Jewish faith is increasing, the ability to find Kosher food is on the decline. Even the local Kosher grocery store sells made in Italy pepperoni pizza.

How can we increase the demand for Kosher food amongst those who believe in Judiasm?

Comment: Is this a question about Judaism?

Comment: @jake - I think it is certainly a question about Jewish life. It is a question of believers in Judaism matching practice to their belief. It could be a question about adult education or motivation.

Comment: ...However, the title is misleading since the question does not mention any acceptability judgment about Hartfordians' practice.

Comment: Are you asking how to convince Jews to keep Kosher, or are you asking how to convince (get) stores to carry Kosher?

Comment: Hold on, is the "Made in Italy" pepperoni pizza vegetarian? Or is your local "Kosher" grocery store selling treif? I'm confused.

Comment: @McGovernTheory - I live up near Hartford also --- I just keep asking for items at the Crown Market in West Hartford, sometimes they'll get a few in to see how they sell...

Answer (score 15):

Start by creating a demand. Every time you walk in to any store that sells food, ask "Do you have Kosher food".

On subsequent visits, ask about particular foods: "Don't have have the Kosher Pizza made by XYZ?"

Try meeting the Marketing Manager or owner and presenting them with a "plan": Create a Kosher Section and see how many extra customers you get, with targeted ads.

Once there's plenty Kosher available, start a *Eat Kosher* campaign.

Comment: ...Get other people to do the same.

Comment: As @yydl commented above, this only addresses the question of convincing stores to carry Kosher. It seems though that the question was about convincing Jews to keep Kosher. The former mostly presents an inflated demand, but doesn't actually increase it.

Comment: @Hartzl - thanks for reminding me - I never finished the post.